# Uncaught (in promise) Error:createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to make simple API Fetch with axios through a simple form,input,
and everything works fine untill I pass user into my axio get.'

first error: GET https://api.github.com/users/$%7Buser%7D 404
second error: createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
'''

```
  function App() {

  let getUser = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  const user = e.target.elements.username.value  

  axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/${user}")
  .then((res) => {
  console.log(res)
  })

  }

 return (

<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <h1 className="App-title">HTTP&API</h1>
  </header>
    <UserForm getUser={getUser}/>
</div>
  );
 }
```

'''

I am new to a web dev, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you just visit the URL on a normal browser, you can see that it says not found. Fix the URL.

Answer (score 1):

either concatenate the string

```
axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + user)
```

or use template strings

```
axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
```

Comment: axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/${user}") 

axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)

so actually all I had to do is change this "" to this '', ty for a fast response it was really helpful.